# SilverStripe dummy page / menu item

Tags: silverstripe

Imagine a site structure / menu layout like this:

Home
About us
**Services**
__Peeling potatoes
__Slicing potatoes
__Baking potatoes

All menu items link to a real page, with their own URL and content. But the bolded item is merely a menu item without a link, content nor URL and it's only purpose is to fold out the submenu on hover. SilverStripe doesn't allow you to create such a Page entity out-of-the-box.

**I'm looking for the cleanest, most simple and least hacky way to create a dummy page merely to function as a menu item**, no content and in the best case also without a URL slug (the latter might be difficult).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve the "dummy" page without any additional code, by just creating a `RedirectorPage` and select your first sub-page as redirection target.

Personally, I've used a even simpler version of a "RedirectorPage" in the past, one that automatically redirects to the first child-page if it were visited directly.

Example:

```
class ChildRedirectorPage extends Page 
{
    private static $description = 'Page that has no content but automatically redirects to the first of its child-pages';

    public function ContentSource() {
        if($firstChild = $this->Children()->First()) {
            return $firstChild;
        } else {
            return $this;
        }       
    }

    public function Link($action = null) {
        // prevent link "redirection" when we're in CMS
        if (!is_subclass_of(Controller::curr(),'LeftAndMain')){
            if($firstChild = $this->Children()->First()) return $firstChild->Link($action);
            else return parent::Link($action);
        }
    }

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
        $fields->removeByName('Content', true);
        return $fields;
    }
}

class ChildRedirectorPage_Controller extends Page_Controller 
{
    function init() {
        parent::init();
        if($firstChild = $this->Children()->First()) {
            $this->redirect($firstChild->Link(), 301);
        }           
    }
}
```

I think the URL slug is actually beneficial, since your URLs will then be `services/peeling-potatoes`, etc. which is most likely better for SEO purposes.